# GA eCommerce delete or update tracking data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

We have eCommerce tracking from our php backend app, but we found issue where not all events in last year pushed to GA.

We have all data in our DB. Its there options to reset, delete or update collected data on GA and push new from our app with datetime of creation (2018-03-12 13:49:51, ..)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there will be no way for you to add in the old data. Your only option would be mergeing it using date or some identifier using something like google datastudio/powerbi/tableau.